# What's difference between 'fall on the ground' and 'hit the ground'?

Tags: difference

I feel like 'fall on the ground' means you fall unintentionally by mistake while 'hit the ground' means to get to the ground intentionally and urgently. Do they have this difference? Or do they convey the same meaning without nuances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To *hit the ground* doesn't quite mean *to fall**: it's more a **consequence** or the **result** of falling on the ground. First, you fall, and *then* you hit the ground.

[image]

The girl *falls* (image 1) and then *hits the ground* (image 2). If you put the actions together, the girl **falls on the ground**. You could also say she **falls to the ground**.

---

*I forgot to mention: in some cases, *hit the ground* **can** mean *intentionally (and urgently) get to the ground*. For example, if someone wants you to lie on the floor, they could say "*Hit the ground!*" The distinction between doing this and "falling," however, lies in the fact that you're **told** to do it (i.e. can hit the ground *voluntarily*), so you're not deliberately going to injure yourself by falling like people do by accident.

Answer (score 0):

Both "fall flat on the ground" and "hit the ground running" are idiomatic expressions.

- To fall flat on the ground means to fail disastrously.  There are other variations of this expression that mean the same thing such as "to fall flat on your face."
- To hit the ground running means to have momentum or to preform a new task in a way that surpasses expectations.
- To fall on the ground means just what it says with no idiomatic meaning.  Your understanding of the phrase seems to be correct.
- To hit the ground itself doesn't necessarily convey urgency; however, any situation that one would be in that would require one to "hit the ground" or take cover would be an urgent situation.

Comment: I don't think idiomatic expressions like your first two examples are what OP is looking for. Also - quick note - I think the expression you're looking for in your first example is "to fall flat **on your face**".